# Calling Javascript functions from JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a JSP file, `page.jsp` and a Javascript, `script.js`

I am trying to call the `script.js` file from my JSP so that the content from the `script.js` file will show up in the JSP pages source.

I would like the `script.js` file to have two functions. One function calls the second function with parameters.

```
function A() {
    b(firstCall);
    b(secondCall);
}
function B(value) {
    document.write(<script>value</script>);
}
```

I need `<script>value</script>` to show up exactly like that in the source of the page in the broswer.

This is how I am calling it from my JSP file,

```
<tiles:insert page="/js/fooBar.js" />
```

But it is not working, as in the the code is not showing up in the page source in my browser. Is my javascript page not set up properly? I am fairly new to JS, so if someone could provide an example of how to do this properly, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got at least two major problems with your JavaScript before I even look at your JSP (which I know nothing about).

Comment: please describe your problem completely and also display the necessary codes and error you get .

Comment: The `jsp` is run in a server, and the parsed `HTML` is send to client.  Then how do you expect to call js function from jsp..?

Answer (score 0):

Inserting file with javascript code done this way:

```
 <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" />"></script>
```

(in your page's head)

Also your 'document.write' is so 2000-ish.., and its arguments:

```
<script>value</script>
```

what result do you expect to have? You may try to print it in single quotes (as string) but still - what's the point of doing this?